# Validating shape type of input feature layers in Python Toolbox of ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-toolbox, validation

How can I get in explorer folder window a layer in specify shape?

For example allow:

[image]

How can We look, explorer after click INPUT FEATURES, shows a layers only points type.

How can I get validate effect like this?

Comment: Have a look at the filter property of the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open python toolbox file (.pyt) in any editor. Edit `updateParameters` method like this: (I assume that `Input Features` is the first parameter, whose index is 0)

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    self.params[0].filter.list = ["POINT"]

    # or if you want another type, use ["LINE", "POLYGON"]
    
    # other lines
            
    return
```

For detailed information: [Filter - Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/filter.htm)